Cookie gets removed on refreshing or reload -- express/cookie/jwt
Cookie gets removed on refreshing or reload: I am using express js to set cookie and react as a frontend:
Can anyone explain why coocki gets deleted after refreshing page?....please help as soon as possible
i am sharing files to inspect for your reference:
Deployed site for your reference: https://shoppynexxa.vercel.app/
jwtToken.js -- backend
const sendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
    const token = user.getJWTToken();

    const options = {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRE * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        domain: "shoppynexxa-backend.onrender.com",
    }

    res.cookie("token", token, options);

    res.status(statusCode).json({
        success: true,
        user,
        token,
    });
}

module.exports = sendToken;

login controller from where sendToken is being called after verifying user: -- backend
//Login User
exports.loginUser = tryCatchWrapper(async (req, res, next) => {

    const { email, password } = req.body;

    //checking weather email and password entered by user or not
    if (!email || !password) {
        return (next(new ErrorHandler("Please Enter Email And Password", 400)))
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select("+password");

    //checking weather user is exist or not
    if (!user) {
        return (next(new ErrorHandler("Invalid Email or Password", 401)));
    }

    //compare password entered by user and db password
    const isPasswordMatched = await user.comparePassword(password);

    if (!isPasswordMatched) {
        return (next(new ErrorHandler("Invalid Email Or Password", 401)))
    }

    if(user.emailVerified) {
        sendToken(user, 200, res);
    } else {
        await sendVerificationEmail(user, res);
        return;
    }
});

api.js for centralizing api calls -- frontend
// src/api.js
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://shoppynexxa-backend.onrender.com', // Set your base URL 
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Example header
    }
});

export default api;

useraction.js from where api call for login made: -- frontend
//Login
export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_REQUEST });

        const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, withCredentials: true}

        const { data } = await api.post(
            `/api/v1/login`,
            { email, password },
            config,
        );

        if (data.mailSent) {
            dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAIL, emailVerification: !data.mailSent })
        } else {
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                payload: data.user,
            })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        // console.log("error", error);
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAIL, payload: error.response.data.message })
    }
}

suggestions how can i tackle this.

Share the Set-Cookie header that your API sets.

Hi, At present the cookies must be sameSite='Lax' which is the default setting. In this case, since it is a CORS case, it must be sameSite='none'.
